# Coin tossing simulation to get x heads in a row, ten times - timely at higher amount of heads

Tags: c#, performance, beginner, console, simulation

I have created a program to simulate a coin being tossed to land on heads/tails x amount of times in a row, where x can be defined by the user. The program then gets x amount of heads in a row, a fixed ten times. This is to generate an average.

```
using System;

namespace HeadsStreak
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a head streak to get. This will be executed ten times to generate an average.");
            int desiredStreak = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int grandTotalAttempts = 0;
            int executionCount = 1;
            int currentStreak = 0;
            int totalAttempts = 0;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            do
            {
                while (currentStreak != desiredStreak)
                {
                    if (rnd.Next(0, 2) == 0)
                    {
                        currentStreak += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentStreak = 0;
                    }
                    totalAttempts += 1;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Attempt Number: {0}", executionCount);
                Console.WriteLine("Total Attempts: {0}", totalAttempts);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                grandTotalAttempts += totalAttempts;
                executionCount += 1;
                currentStreak = 0;
                totalAttempts = 0;
            } while (executionCount <= 10);
            Console.WriteLine("Average Attempts: {0}", grandTotalAttempts/10);    
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say I ask for fifteen heads. The console may look something like this:

```
Enter a head streak to get. This will be executed five times to generate an average.
15
Attempt Number: 1
Total Attempts: 82761

Attempt Number: 2
Total Attempts: 42464

Attempt Number: 3
Total Attempts: 157531

Attempt Number: 4
Total Attempts: 79750

Attempt Number: 5
Total Attempts: 19214

Attempt Number: 6
Total Attempts: 4573

Attempt Number: 7
Total Attempts: 8161

Attempt Number: 8
Total Attempts: 99553

Attempt Number: 9
Total Attempts: 41036

Attempt Number: 10
Total Attempts: 84431

Average Attempts: 61947
```

This can execute fairly quickly within a reasonable timeframe. Time issues begin at 24, I assume this is because it takes 2^24 attempts to get 24 heads in a row. However, I am wondering if there is anything to improve in the code in order to improve performance so that higher streaks can be achieved within a reasonable timeframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fails if they don't enter an integer
You are doing integer math on the average
I would prefer `++;` over `+= 1;`
I would rather see a `foreach`
Odd but `rnd.Next(2)` is faster
Need to get into the millions for a decent sample

```
public static void CoinToss()
{
    int sample = 1000000;
    Debug.WriteLine($"Enter a head streak to achieve. This will be executed {sample.ToString("N0")} times to generate an average.");
    int desiredStreak = 10;  
    int grandTotalAttempts = 0;
    int currentStreak;
    int totalAttempts;
    Random rnd = new Random();            
    for (int i = 0; i < sample; i++)
    {
        currentStreak = 0;
        totalAttempts = 0;
        while (currentStreak != desiredStreak)
        {
            if (rnd.Next(2) == 0)
            {
                currentStreak ++;
            }
            else
            {
                currentStreak = 0;
            }
            totalAttempts ++;
        }
        if ((i + 1) % (sample / 20) == 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Attempt Number: {(i + 1).ToString("N0")}");
            Debug.WriteLine($"Total Attempts: {totalAttempts.ToString("N0")}");
            Debug.WriteLine("");
        }
        grandTotalAttempts += totalAttempts;  
    }
    Debug.WriteLine($"Average Attempts: {((decimal)grandTotalAttempts / sample).ToString("N2")}");
}
```

Comment: Use a `foreach` to iterate over an array with the attempts in it?

Comment: No executionCount